# Angular 2 - Using md-hint With A mdDatepicker Input

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am new to `Angular 2` and i am having touble using `md-hint` with a `mdDatepicker`.

I can get it working with `md-select` and 'input'.

**HTML that doesn't work**

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Start date" name="startDatepicker" required ngModel #startDatepicker="ngModel">
    <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="startDatepicker"></button>
    <md-hint *ngIf="startDatepicker.errors && (startDatepicker.dirty || startDatepicker.touched)" [hidden]="!startDatepicker.errors.required">
        Start date is required.
    </md-hint>                    
</md-input-container>
```

**HTML that does work (Input Only field)**

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Start date" name="startDatepicker" required ngModel #startDatepicker="ngModel">
    <md-hint *ngIf="startDatepicker.errors && (startDatepicker.dirty || startDatepicker.touched)" [hidden]="!startDatepicker.errors.required">
        Start date is required.
    </md-hint>                    
</md-input-container>
```

All i did with the code that does work was on the `input`, remove `[mdDatepicker]="startDatepicker"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, both of the codes that you posted throws some errors. Why?

1 - You're missing `[mdDatepicker]="yourRefToDatePicker"` in your `input`;

2 - `[mdDatepickerToggle]` should point to a datepicker instance (not to ngModel as you're doing):

```
[mdDatepickerToggle]="yourRefToDatePicker"
```

3 - You should have an instance of `md-datepicker`:

```
<md-datepicker #yourRefToDatePicker></md-datepicker>
```

---

Here's a working example using `md-datepicker`:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput
         placeholder="Start date"
         name="startDatepicker"
         required
         ngModel
         [mdDatepicker]="picker"
         #startDatepicker="ngModel">
  <button type="button" mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
  <md-hint *ngIf="startDatepicker.errors && (startDatepicker.dirty || startDatepicker.touched)" [hidden]="!startDatepicker.errors.required">
    Start date is required.
  </md-hint>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

---

That said, here are some notes:

1 - There's no point in using `*ngIf` and `[hidden]` at the same element (and you should also prefer `*ngIf`).

If you want to check only the `required` *error* you can do this (use `md-error` as 2nd. statement below):

```
<md-hint *ngIf="startDatepicker.errors?.required && (startDatepicker.dirty || startDatepicker.touched)">
  Start date is required.
</md-hint>
```

2 - To show errors using **Material2** is recommended to use `md-error` *directive*, like this:

```
<md-error *ngIf="condition">
  <!-- your error message -->
</md-error>
```

---

The final code could be something like this:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput
       placeholder="Start date"
       name="startDatepicker"
       required
       ngModel
       [mdDatepicker]="picker"
       #startDatepicker="ngModel">
  <button type="button" mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
</md-input-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="startDatepicker.invalid && (startDatepicker.dirty || startDatepicker.touched)">
  <md-error *ngIf="startDatepicker.hasError('required')">
    Start date is required.
  </md-error>
  <md-error *ngIf="startDatepicker.getError('mdDatepickerMax') as datepickerMaxError">
    Start date should be less than {{ datepickerMaxError.max }}
  </md-error>
  <!-- another error(s) -->
</ng-container>

<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KEECNZluNb8jHWTnR8Xp)

Comment: Are you able to do a pluker which will validate if i have 2 date fields start/end date and if the start date is after the end date the error msg is displayed.